# Divide command prompt into multiple lines

Tags: command-line, prompt

When working on the terminal like:

```
algorithms@assistant:~$ ls
Desktop    Downloads  Music     Public  Templates         Videos
Documents  gtd.org    Pictures  snap    version-check.sh
```

the command `ls` is constantly aligned with `username@hostname`.

How could I separate them into independent lines? Example:

```
algorithms@assistant:
~$ ls
```

Comment: Add a "`\n`" (newline) at the relevant place in the PS1 variable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A bit more detail of **Soren A** comment. Edit the file .bashrc with editor.

```
editor ~/.bashrc
```

Then lockup for the following line

```
PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]\$ '
```

Add the \n (new line) special character just before the \$ at the end of the line. You should have a line looks like :

```
PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]\n\$ '
```